# Can a vampire heal itself?

Tags: creature-design, vampires

If a vampire gets a cut or stabbed or just injured in general will it be able to heal itself? And will blood come out? I remember learning last term that to heal yourself you just make new cells?

Comment: Well, it really depends on the vampire. There are a wide variety of vampires today, from the old giant-bat like vampires to the more human ones of today. And since different kind of vampires have different kinds of abilities and biology, it just depends. I mean, mosquitoes can heal themselves, so why not vampires?

Comment: I think that this question could benefit from some reworking. I think maybe if you ask about **how** they could heal (as opposed to **if** they could), maybe add some parameters for these vampires, then it'll give people more to work with. Otherwise people are going to close as too broad or opinion based.

Comment: Since known methods for killing vampires are way less than those for killing humans, it is clear that, yes, they can heal themselves. So what are you exactly asking?

Comment: It depends, some species are known to bite their wounds. The bite introduces anticlogging enzymes to promote blood flow and also pain killer to numb the affected area so that the vampire will not try to scratch it and doing so to make it worst. And there's mucus...

Comment: Its realy just a matter of opinion

Answer (score 2):

**The odds of this question being closed as "primarily opinion-based" are unbelievably high.**

And the only reason I might get away with this is that I can point to Bram Stoker's *Dracula* and literary analyses to provide some insight.

Vampire stories [preceded Bram Stoker's novel by nearly 200 years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vampire_literature) and show no sign of running out of steam.  During those early years the concept of a "vampire" was investigated, sensationalized, abused, and refined.  The fundamental concept of a vampire was more than a little solidified by Bram Stoker because (a) he was a whomping good writer and (b) he had the advantage of "modern" printing and distribution (in 1897) which meant a lot of people came to think of vampires the way he did.

In Bram Stoker's novel, a vampire heals faster than normal people and rejuvenates (grows younger) from drinking blood.

*If I want to stretch a long, long way, I could suggest that whatever it is that makes a vampire the "living undead" (be it magic, a virus, a curse, or nanites) that "something" is able to extract from living blood what is needed to allow what would otherwise be dead and inoperative cells to do the voodoo that they do to heal.*

However, because vampires are utterly fictional, people can and have defined them to be whatever they wished them to be for the sake of their story.  Almost inevitably, the creature is sensual (because [sex sells](http://www.businessnewsdaily.com/2649-sex-sells-more.html)), the creature is insanely powerful (be it strength, skills, or abilities... like turning into a [<s>black chicken</s> bat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8bnER7kl1Q)), and the creature has a [ridiculous weakness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_vampire_traits_in_folklore_and_fiction) like garlic.  I mean, really, what's not to like about garlic?

By the way, that last link will give you amazing insight into the wide variation of vampiric strengths and weaknesses over the centuries.  It's very thorough, including even the weakness of the Count Chocula breakfast cereal (the writers have an excellent sense of humor!).  I recommend taking a peek!

**But, to answer your question: focusing only on Bram Stoker's *Dracula:* Yes, they will heal.  Possibly they will bleed, depending on when they enjoyed their last meal.**

Comment: I downvoted because you acknowledge the fact that this question is bad as it is of noe - yet you still proceed to answer it instead of helping the OP making it better.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T Your phrase "as it is of noe" leaves me totally baffled. Can you translate it into plain English to help my confused mind comprehend what you said. JBH said the odds for its closure were high. This is a reasonable judgement based on questions that are closed as POB. The answer does provide guidance for the OP to improve their question by discussing the most well-known literary example of a vampire. What's not to like about that?

Comment: @a4android it's a typo. If you look at a keyboard you will find that the letters 'e' and 'w' are next to each other.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T, :-) I fully acknowledge and accept the downvote!  I answered for the purely selfish reason that it was fun.  (*sigh*), sometimes it happens.  (You don't have something against garlic, do you?)  :-)

Comment: @JBH sadly I fully understand that it is fun to dig into the subjects of opinion-based questions. I also quite understand that summarizing and sharing what you find is the best part of it. But it also does not help users to write *good* questions - in fact it provokes the opposite; just spam bad questions, you'll get a hand full of answers anyways.... Also I love garlic!

Comment: @dot_Sp0T Your clarification has cleared away my confusion. Now I feel almost enlightened! Especially after I fixing my own typos in drafting this comment.

Comment: @a4android I am glad we could work this out.